# How do I add specific package from a base environment to an existing conda environment?

Tags: julia, conda

I have julia 1.4.2 in my base environment and julia 1.6.0 in my new_env. I want to install 1.4.2 in my new_env from my base environment. How do I do it?

Comment: How exactly are you adding Julia to your conda environment?

Comment: If what you want is just the packages from the 1.4.2 version in the julia installed in `new_env` you can do `using Pkg; Pkg.activate("v1.4",shared=true)` from the julia 1.6.0 installed in `new_env`.

Answer (score 1):

Julia is not officially distributed using conda, only some independent individuals are adding different julia versions to conda. Thus, you will always struggle with finding proper versions, because no-one added all version of julia to conda.

E.g. https://anaconda.org/RMG/julia has julia versions 1.6.0 and 1.4.2 which is probably what you want, but there you need to specify the channel `rmg` in order to make it work.

But I would advise not to install julia through conda and encourage to use the recommended way of installing julia from https://julialang.org/downloads/ or `wget` it from there.
E.g. I use this to install julia on Linux

```
cd ~ && \
wget https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/1.6/julia-1.6.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz && \
tar xvfz julia-1.6.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz && \
mkdir -p ~/bin && \
ln -s ~/julia-1.6.1/bin/julia ~/bin/julia
```

Comment: what's the recommended way of installing julia?

Comment: From https://julialang.org/downloads/ 
in case you need to script it, just wget it like this.
`wget https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/<julia tarball>
tar zxvf <that name>`, e.g. for 1.6.2
`wget https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/1.6/julia-1.6.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
tar zxvf julia-1.6.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz`